# Inverse Laplace Transform including s^a

Tags: convolution, inverse-laplace

If I have the relation in the Laplace domain as below, then how can I have an inverse transform in the time domain?

H(s)=(K_1^(-a_1)(1/(s^a_1+K^(-a_1)))*(K_2^(-a_2)*(1/(s^a_2+K^(-a_2)))

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please convert your formula to Mathjax so its easier to make sense of it. Is this what you mean?

$$H(s)=\frac{1}{K_1^{a_1}\left(s^{a_1}+K^{-a_1}\right)}\ \frac{1}{K_2^{a_2}\left(s^{a_2}+K^{-a_2}\right)}$$

Comment: Sorry for bothering you due to my lack of knowledge of Mathjax.  The above formula you made is what I mean except for two terms such as K^-a_1 -> K_1^-a_1 and K^-a_2 -> K_2^-a_2